httpd.service entered failed state
we are experiencing some weird issues with the httpd.service, it doesn't start
Please let me know if you know by any chance how to resolve this issue
Failed to start the Apache HTTP Server/ job for httpd.service failed because control process exited with error code
even if we add ServerName 127.0.0.1 - it doesn't fix the problem at the end of sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Any help would be greatly appreciated! below are some logs
[root@freepbx ~]# sudo systemctl restart httpd.service 
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. 
[root@freepbx ~]# sudo systemctl start httpd.service 
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. 
[root@freepbx ~]# systemctl status httpd.service 
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled) 
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-10-21 17:34:19 AEDT; 3s ago 
Docs: man:httpd(8) man:apachectl(8) 
Process: 29645 
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
Main PID: 29645 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 21 17:34:19 freepbx.sangoma.local systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server... Oct 21 17:34:19 freepbx.sangoma.local systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
Oct 21 17:34:19 freepbx.sangoma.local systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. 
Oct 21 17:34:19 freepbx.sangoma.local systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state. 
Oct 21 17:34:19 freepbx.sangoma.local systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
[root@freepbx ~]# cd /var/log/httpd 
[root@freepbx httpd]# tail -f error_log 
[Mon Oct 21 17:34:10.305554 2024] [suexec:notice] [pid 29635] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec) 
[Mon Oct 21 17:34:10.309979 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29635] AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain! 
[Mon Oct 21 17:34:10.309989 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29635] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. 
[Mon Oct 21 17:34:19.136853 2024] [suexec:notice] [pid 29645] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec) 
[Mon Oct 21 17:34:19.137369 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29645] AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain! 
[Mon Oct 21 17:34:19.137377 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 29645] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.

I am expecting to start httpd.service
Rebooting, upgrading, refreshing, reloading the freepbx server
I have tried adding ServerName 127.0.0.1 - it doesn't fix the problem at the end of sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

The logs you've shown us tell you exactly what the problem is. You didn't think to include the relevant parts of the config. It's 2024 - you need a very good reason to still be using suExec. Why did you tag this with Apache-2.2?

enter code here

mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.old
systemctl restart httpd
enter image description here

Here are some possible solutions:

Check the SSL Certificate Configuration:

Ensure that the SSL certificate and key files are located in the correct directories and have the correct permissions.
Verify that the certificate chain is complete and valid.
Double-check the Apache configuration file (usually /etc/apache2/apache2.conf) to ensure that the SSL certificate and key files are specified correctly.

Install Missing Dependencies:

If you're using a package manager like apt or yum, make sure that all necessary dependencies for the mod_ssl module are installed. You might need to run a command like sudo apt install libapache2-mod-ssl or sudo yum install mod_ssl.

Update Apache:

If you're using an older version of Apache, updating to a newer version might resolve the issue.

Check for Conflicts:

If you have installed any custom modules or configurations that might be interfering with mod_ssl, try disabling them temporarily to see if the problem persists.
